# identify same identical values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wanting to return duplicate values  row-wise, instead of by columns. Using below, `df` returns duplicate values by a col, but I'm hoping to pass the same function row-wise. Is it possible with the same method?

The output will contain all duplicate values between the columns but mapped **row-wise**. Not column-wise. So index 0 contains duplicates in `bar`, row 1 contains  duplicates in `foo` and `bar` etc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","foo","B","bar"], "D":["bar","bar","B","foo"], "E":["bar","bar","B","foo"]
                })

df['dup']=df['A']
df['dup'].loc[~df['A'].duplicated(keep='first')]=''
```

df2 intended output:

```
     A  B    C    D    E      dup
0  foo  0    A  bar  bar      bar
1  foo  1  foo  bar  bar foo, bar
2  foo  1    B    B    B        B
3  bar  1  bar  foo  foo bar, foo
```

Comment: Please clearly explain the logic behind creating desired  output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
df2["dup"] = df2.apply(lambda x: set([i for i in x if x.tolist().count(i) > 1]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A  B    C    D    E         dup
0  foo  0    A  bar  bar       {bar}
1  foo  1  foo  bar  bar  {foo, bar}
2  foo  1    B    B    B         {B}
3  bar  1  bar  foo  foo  {foo, bar}
```